# Android 4.4 compatible ir code format?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, infrared

I've just noticed that android 4.4 has an api for ir controls. The problem is: you have to send an int array({11,12,13,14...}) however, it's nearly impossible to find ir codes in that format. Could anyone explain or just give a link where explains those ir code formats? Just for example: how can I translate the ir hex codes I found from the user manual of my projector to the int array format to use in my app? I'm sorry for this noob question. I'm really a noob when it comes to ir :(

Answer (score 0):

Simply just convert the hex codes to ints. The first number is the frequency. Other numbers are on/off alternating pattern as documentation says.

for example:
"38000, 168, 81, 12, 255"
Means: with frequency: 38kHz (38000 blinks of led per seconds)
On: 168 microseconds,
Off 81 microsecconds,
On: 12 microseconds,
off: 255 microseconds

Answer (score -1):

Hey check our this post he explains where to find some ir codes and translate them into use fuel info with the transmite function in the consumerirmanager class

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25518468/3731190